# change dropdown menu from hover to onclick

Tags: css

i am looking for dropdown menu ( onlcick )

after many searches, finally i have found one

but the problem is, the code i have is based on ( hover ) Not ( onclick )

i want convert the code to be onclick instead of hover, by javascript or css

My Code:

```
<style>
ul.dropdown,
ul.dropdown li,
ul.dropdown ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

ul.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 597;
 float: left;
}

ul.dropdown li {
 float: left;
 min-height: 1px;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 599;
 cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown ul {
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 598;
 width: 100%;
}

ul.dropdown ul li {
 float: none;
}

ul.dropdown ul ul {
 top: 1px;
 left: 99%;
}

ul.dropdown li:hover > ul {
 visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="./" class="dir">Download Drivers</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Download Drivers</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Driver Widget</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">NVIDIA Software</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="./" class="dir">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">Desktop</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Workstation</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Servers</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">Motherboard</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="./" class="dir">Technologies</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="./">NVIDIA SLI</a></li>
            <li><a href="./">NVIDIA Hybrid SLI</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take out the `:hover` in the css, because this is what controls it hovering.  You need to put something in some javascript like `<li onclick="showUL();">Text</li>` I would use jQuery...

Comment: either jquery or plain javascript can solve this, because you need to bind the links with the click event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this the effect you want? See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UQwJz/4/ [edited]

I have reinvented your css and made it simpler.

Comment: this is my problem http://jsfiddle.net/UQwJz/1/ see this, try to click on any menu, The other divs will go to the end of the page!!! i wish if you understand my problem!

Comment: Nice, it's exactly what i want, But can you replace the jquery code by javascript? i dont use jquery in my design

Comment: Oh sorry, javascript would take a lot of coding. You can use the JS as suggested by Ameoo below.

Comment: Okay, here is the JS version (using Ameoo's code below) that I expanded so the other menu would auto-hide when a new sub menu is clicked. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UQwJz/4/ I just hope you do me a favor by upvoting my answer.

Comment: JSFiddle not working - showing spam detected. If possible kindly update

Comment: @Ronnie Try https://jsfiddle.net/7L5p8eLu/
(The [Internet Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150601000000*/http://jsfiddle.net/UQwJz/4/) still had it, but I had to make a couple of changes to get it to work for whatever reason).

Answer (score 1):

1)Modify the css for the menus that you want to drop down, by adding a `display:none;` (this will make them not show up)

2)Assign an `id` to the root menu item and another one which can be built using the first one to the list under the root item ( that you want to have dropped down)

3)in the same element declaration, have `onclick=dropdown()` . Example

`<li id='menu1' onclick=dropdown()><ul id='menu1menu' >` which will cal the dropdown function on clicking on that element.

```
<li><a href="./" id='drivers' onclick=dropdown() class="dir">Download Drivers</a>
    <ul id='driversmenu'>
        <li><a href="./">Download Drivers</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Driver Widget</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">NVIDIA Software</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

4)have this function:
   On click, the function will check if the ul under the li is displayed or not, then make it have an opposite display value.
     You can use the same function for all menus, granted that you give your uls the same id as the parent li+'menu'.

```
  function dropdown()
        {
            if(document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display=='block'){
                document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='none';
            }
            else{ 
                document.getElementById(window.event.srcElement.id+'menu').style.display='block';
            }
        };
```

Comment: i have tryied it before, the problem is in css, after i change div from none to block, div will affect the size of page the boxes other boxes will be affected and will go down, my dropdown box should be something like absolute ( to not affect the other boxes in the page )

Comment: then make the ul position absolute. :)