# How to change hover menu to clickable menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the above example shows when hover the dropdown menu it displays submenu , I want the submenu display after clicking the dropdown text.

How to change hovermenu to clickable menu.please help anyone regarding this.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use javascript or jquery and onclick event open submenu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change dropdown menu from hover to onclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228165/change-dropdown-menu-from-hover-to-onclick)

Comment: when i asked question suggestion not came

Comment: have you google it???

Comment: @priya_singh the accepted answer on the possible duplicate does refer to external site, where the code is no more available, thus the answer is de facto "empty".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `toggle` option to make it work

**Updated** I made it more dynamic so you can have more dropdowns if you want

```js
$('.dropbtn').click(function () {
  var isvisible = $(this).next('.dropdown-content').is(":visible")
  $('.dropdown-content:visible').hide();
  if (!isvisible)
    {
      $(this).next('.dropdown-content').toggle()
    }
})
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you! so much!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i have same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743728/bootstrap-on-click-menu-scroll-up-when-clicked

Answer (score 0):

For Selenium, I would try the following snippet:

```
WebDriver driver = new xDriver(); // where 'x' = any Browser driver
Actions obj = new Actions(driver);
WebElement y = driver.findElement(By.LinkText("TextName"));
obj.moveToElement (y).perform();
```

'WebDriver', 'Actions' and 'WebElement" are classes.